# Why <section> is not making a new section in the outline

Tags: html

I'm learning about outlines in HTML5 on my own.

This is my code:

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body> 
 <header>
  <h1>Site Header</h1>
 </header>
 <section>
  <h1>Site Content</h1>
 </section>
 <footer>
  <h1>Site Footer</h1>
 </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

And the outliner show this:

1. Site Header

   1. Site Content
2. Site Footer

My question is: why my `<section>` is inside the `<header>` (in the outline)? I've read that `<header>`, `<section>` and `<footer>` are sectioning elements, so my `<section>` should make a new section in the outline, right? But why is inside another section?

Comment: What is “the outliner”? It works just fine for me.

Comment: I think the OP means https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/html5_outliner/

Comment: Why don't you use https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/ instead? By the way, what you pasted here is probably not what you are getting a problem with. I'm guessing you are missing closing tags

Comment: @Xufox Im using this https://gsnedders.html5.org/outliner/

Answer (score -1):

Try using a simple div? It works just as easy.

```
<div class="whatever">

</div>
```

CSS accessing

```
.whatever {
   text-align: center; // Whatever
   width: 200px; // Whatever
}
```

Comment: The OP’s trying to use the new HTML5 tags. Simply replacing them with `<div>` tags isn’t an acceptable answer and doesn’t answer the actual question.